# Client code: Finding which radio button is checked

Tags: dom, forms, dhtml

In Javascript code on the browser, given the `name` of a group of radio buttons, is there a way to directly find out which button is checked without iterating through each button one by one to check its `checked` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes with jQuery. If the name of the group is `state`, then:

```
$("[name=state]:checked").val()
```